# How to use bootstrap and what is the latest bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a user php registration project. My senior told me use bootsrap framework. So I included js, css folders to that project. But still have no idea how to use them. Please give me some example. or a link work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version is Bootstrap 3.0.3. You can find it [here](http://getbootstrap.com).

How to use  it ?

Bootstrap provides you a lot of preset CSS and JS components. You just have to include both `.css` and `.js` files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

...and start to use the classes provided !

An exemple, to get a few Bootstrap buttons ([see the result here](http://bootply.com/99345)) :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
```

You'll find everything you need on http://getbootstrap.com/ :

- Grid system
- Typography
- Tables
- Forms
- Buttons
- Utility classes
- Glyphicons
- Dropdowns
- Navbar
- Pagination
- Alerts
- Panels
- Modal
- Carousel
- ...

Comment: thanks is twitter bootsrap is a version of bootsrap?

Comment: Bootstrap was originaly called Twitter Bootstrap. It's the same thing.

Comment: You're welcome. Take the time to read the documentation, to know what you can do with Bootstrap, it can save a big amout of your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the current version of Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/.
On the provided link you can find all documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is the latest bootstrap version : [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/.)

You can find the basic template at the same page. (which styles and js have to be imported).
If you want to customize your bootstrap version (fonts,size and so on), you can do it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

After that, you just have to become a little bit familiar with the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)system and all other predefined css classes, components or javascript-based components.

You can find some kick-off examples : [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)